# How to get a value from a List<Double> and store it into a double

Tags: java, android

I'm getting an Array from Firebase and I want to retrieve the values from the Array (I am able to print them successfully but I cannot store them into a double).

```
List<Double> weight = (List<Double>) data.get("Weight");
int weightLength = weight.size();
double currentWeight = (double) weight.get(weightLength-1);
```

I receive the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
```

Edit:
I changed the List type from Double to Long and I am not able to get an output of "[60]". I have the value 60 stored in my Firebase Cloud Firestore

```
List<Long> weight = (List<Long>) data.get("Weight");
int weightLength = weight.size();
double currentWeight = weight.get(weightLength-1);
```

Comment: Are you absolutely *sure* the objects in the List are Doubles instead of Longs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data.get("Weight")` returns `List<Long>` that you tried to cast to `List<Double>` which is not allowed e.g. the following code won't even pass compilation:

```
List<Long> list = List.of(1L, 2L);
List<Double> weight = (List<Double>) list;
```

So, the solution is to declare `weight` of the type, `List<Long>` i.e.

```
List<Long> weight = (List<Long>) data.get("Weight");
```

Also, you do not need to cast a `long` explicitly to `double` i.e. the following line

```
double currentWeight = (double) weight.get(weightLength-1);
```

can be simply written without an explicit cast as

```
double currentWeight = weight.get(weightLength - 1);
```

Comment: This works however it gives me "[60]" instead of the desired "60", could you please explain as to why that is ?

Comment: @JoshMunstermann - You are getting `[60]` because `System.out.println(weight);` automatically gets converted to `System.out.println(weight.toString());` and if you look at the documentation of [ArrayList#toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString--), you will find that it returns a string of elements enclosed by `[ ]`. However, `System.out.println(weight.get(weightLength - 1))` will give you `60`. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt/issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I need to use .toString() because I'm trying to setText(). Is there a way I can overcome that ?

Comment: @JoshMunstermann - Yes, you can use `setText(String.valueOf(weight.get(weightLength - 1)))` . If you want to set the complete `List`, you can do `setText(weight.toString().replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", ""))`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that long can be cast to double, but not Long. Two solutions:

Leave long-to-double to the compiler, and just ensure long:

```
double currentWeight = (long) weight.get(weightLength-1);
```

Use that long, Long, int, Integer and all are Number, with conversion functions:

```
double currentWeight = weight.get(weightLength-1).doubleValue();
```

The latter is nicest IMHO.

I saw that @fatma zehra güç gave this error, probably before the OP's edit.